# Python multiline regular expression

Tags: python, regex, multiline

```
input = """
endless gibberish
some more stuff

color texture mytexture
    [640 480 1]
    'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
    'BE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBE4C16FF'
    'BF4C16FFBF4C16FFBE4B15FFBE4B15FFBC4913FFBC4913FFBC4913FFBB4812FFBC4913FF'
    'BC4A14FFBB4913FFBB4812FFBB4812FFBA4812FFBA4812FFBB4913FFBC4A16FFBB4915FF'
    'B84612FFB84612FFB94713FFB84612FFB64410FFB64410FFB64410FFB4420EFFB3410DFF'
    'FB03E0AFFB13F0BFB13F0BFFAE3C08FFAA3804FFAD3B07FFB03E0AFFB3410DFFB4420EFF'
    'B4400DFFB13D0AFFB23C0AFFB03C09FFB23E0BFFB5410EFFB74310FFB94512FFB84411FF'

color texture mytexture2
    [640 480 1]
    'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
    'BE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBE4C16FF'
    (... etc...)

"""
```

Need to get the stuff between the brackets and the binary blob data after the line with "texture" until the empty line is reached. There's several "texture" paragraphs.

Here's what I got thus far:

```
p = re.compile(r'texture\s+(\S+)\s+\[(\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)\]\s+(\'.+\')')
matches = p.findall(data)
    for match in matches:
         print match[0]
         print match[1]
         print match[2]
         print "---------------"
```

Gives the following output:

```
 mytexture
 640 480 1
 'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
 ---------------
 mytexture2
 640 480 1
 'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
 ---------------
```

I'm pretty sure re.MULTILINE should be used to get the *whole* blob, but its unclear to me how to grab *all* binary lines.
My question basically is: how does one grab multiple lines and know when to "stop" (ie: the empty line is reached).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.MULTILINE` affects the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors. What I think you want here is `re.DOTALL`, without which the `.` character will never match a newline.

To match all of the text up to the next blank line, you'd use something like `(.*?)\n\s*\n`. This seems to do what you're looking for?

```
p = re.compile(r'texture\s+(\S+)\s+\[(\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)\]\s+(.*?)\n\s*\n', re.DOTALL)
matches = p.findall(input)
for match in matches:
    print match[0]
    print match[1]
    print match[2]
    print "---------------"
```

On your sample text, this produces:

```
mytexture
640 480 1
'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
    'BE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBE4C16FF'
    'BF4C16FFBF4C16FFBE4B15FFBE4B15FFBC4913FFBC4913FFBC4913FFBB4812FFBC4913FF'
    'BC4A14FFBB4913FFBB4812FFBB4812FFBA4812FFBA4812FFBB4913FFBC4A16FFBB4915FF'
    'B84612FFB84612FFB94713FFB84612FFB64410FFB64410FFB64410FFB4420EFFB3410DFF'
    'FB03E0AFFB13F0BFB13F0BFFAE3C08FFAA3804FFAD3B07FFB03E0AFFB3410DFFB4420EFF'
    'B4400DFFB13D0AFFB23C0AFFB03C09FFB23E0BFFB5410EFFB74310FFB94512FFB84411FF'
---------------
mytexture2
640 480 1
'BE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FFBE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBD4B15FF'
    'BE4C16FFBE4C16FFBD4B15FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBC4A14FFBE4C16FF'
    (... etc...)
---------------
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks! I attemped re.DOTALL too, but failed to make the regexp "stop" on the empty line. Hence the `(.*?)\n\s*\n` and DOTALL saves my day. Guess I was misunderstanding the MULTILINE flag too :S

Comment: I always have to go back and reread the documentation before using re.MULTILINE to make sure I'm using it properly. :-P

Answer (score 0):

You were spot on, just didn't get so far as to actually implement it ;)

```
import re

input = """
endless gibberish
some more stuff

texture mytexture
    '01AB01AB01AB01BA'
    '01AB01AB01AB01BA'
    '01AB01AB01AB01BA'
    '01AB01AB01AB01BA'

"""

matches = re.findall(r'01AB01AB01AB01BA', input, re.M)
print matches
```

Comment: It makes me wonder if the OP even tried anything, since all you did is take their words and translate them directly into code.

Comment: My bad. And I was rightly punished by -2 rep. Hope the edited post is more clear.